# Adobe Photoshop: Creating a matrix grid / collage of images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, automation, grids

Is there a convenient way of creating a grid, or a collage of images, without having to do it manually?

Ideally I want a 64x64 square grid of images that are each 100px * 100px. I've seen them done a few times, I think Groupon used to have one.

Are there any plugins that exist for this or any way of doing it without having to resize each image manually?

Comment: Are you looking to construct this in Photoshop? If so, for what type of output? If you are looking for web design, there are things like http://masonry.desandro.com/ which can do this on the web.

Comment: @Scott yes I want to construct in Photoshop and have the output as a PNG.

Comment: Then you have to do it manually. I've never seen any automated processes for masonry layouts within Photoshop. I could be wrong though.

Comment: @Scott I had a feeling I'd end up having to do it manually.

Comment: Possibly related - photoshop extension mentioned [Is there a tool in linux/gimp to dynamically layout a grid of images for scrapbook cutouts?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/61588/is-there-a-tool-in-linux-gimp-to-dynamically-layout-a-grid-of-images-for-scrapbo)

Answer (score 6):

Photoshop used to have a script pre-installed for creating grids of images called contact sheet. It was originally for photographers to print out a grid of images for reviewing.

You can reinstall it though for latest versions:

Windows - http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/thankyou.jsp?ftpID=4688&fileID=4376

Mac - http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4965

Just tweak the settings to get the grid you need.

Comment: There is now 'Contact Sheet II' which maintains this function. Thanks for helping me find it!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread but I thought I'd comment just because it shows up so high in google searches-
There is a script called TychPanel thats not only awesome but free! I would pay so much money for that thing because I use it all the time.

You can find the download and lots of information about it here: http://lumens.se/tychpanel/

The only problem I had was that it was a little tricky to install but it Looks like there's a newer version from the one I have so it might be easier to install than when I did it last.

Comment: Looks spiffy. I'll have to give it a try! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you simply want a grid of images or make a real mosaic where each image will act as a "pixel".

**One way to do grids with Photoshop is to use the "[Contact Sheet  II](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/how-to/create-contact-sheets.html)".** You'll find this in the menu File, then Automate, then Contact Sheet II.

This is quite an old functionality in Adobe Photoshop. It's already installed in Photoshop and haven't changed much in the last 10-15 years.

Very useful if you need to quickly create catalogs for stock images as well  since you can add the name of the file too below each image, if you want.

There you can specify the folder where all your images all, color mode, size of the image, rows/columns, spacing, etc.

Ideally, your images should all be cropped already to be square. That can be done with an action before using the contact sheet. But the size will be adjusted automatically though and your images can have different sizes.

The contact sheet will take all the images in the folder you selected and stick them next to each others automatically. If you want a particular order, you can name your file accordingly (1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, etc.) and select the direction to apply the images.

If you have more images than what can fit on one page, Photoshop will create a new document automatically and will keep going until all the pictures in the folders are used!

I think you cannot use thumbnails smaller than 100px but you can always resize the final result after you're done.

Once the automation is done, you'll have your file with masonry opened in Photoshop and can save it in the format you want.

[image: contact sheet automate photoshop]

**This is an example of a bunch of thumbnails together using the contact sheet:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an photos ready (100x100 px width) you can use an online tool like http://www.photojoiner.net collage maker.

On the photojoiner collage maker set the Width to 200px and height to 800px, then click on "8" from "CHOOSE TEMPLATE", then select a template with 2 rows and 8 columns (pretty much the grid you looking for). once you finish adding the images to the canvas, set the border width to 0. You are done| just download it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these scripts which inluded in CS3?

1. File > Automate > Picture Package
2. File > Automate > Web Photo Gallery
3. File > Automate > Photo Merge

These are some usefull tools to do thing like that you wanted.