# How to stack images in photoshop side by side in a grid? (Automation, Batching)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, sprite, education

How to stack images in photoshop side by side in a grid? In a automated process?

I'm going to have a grid of 3 x 7 (total 21) logos for a website?

Alternatively I could make images seperately and put it in a table how can I save images into the same size and do a batch save of all the images at a certain size.

How to automate logos into one photoshop file with certain size and then save it as jpeg?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [PS: Creating a matrix grid/collage of images](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16948/ps-creating-a-matrix-grid-collage-of-images)

Answer (score 2):

To export multiple same sized images, I'd suggest using layers instead of laying them out. (Stack them in a 1x1 square, not 7x3) There is a script in Photoshop to save out each layer automatically as a separate file.

On a side note, if you want one grided image, there is a script in InDesign that does exactly that: Samples>Javascript folder>ImageCatalog.jsx