# Is there a tool in linux/gimp to dynamically layout a grid of images for scrapbook cutouts?

Tags: print-design, linux

I'm looking for a tool that will layout images into grids ***dynamically*** **without altering their proportions**. The purpose would be to make cutting image printouts much faster for moodboards/scrapbooking. I know a lot of websites can layout images dynamically, taking each image size into consideration. Is it possible to run a commandline tool to achieve something like this? If possible, a grid without borders would be much better.

There is an extension for photoshop that achieves something like this: http://lumens.se/tychpanel/

However, from what I can see, other options in linux aren't dynamic and require that all images have the same aspect-ratio. It would be ok if there is a little space left over at the end of a page (as in the example). The priority is to maintain each images' aspect ratio whilst using as much space as possible on the page.

An example:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @magicalex over on askubuntu, I have found something pretty close to what I was looking for. Sometimes it can crop the images slightly but you can click regenerate to try another arrangement. You can also swap images around by clicking them.

You can download it here:
https://github.com/adrienverge/PhotoCollage

[image]